# ng-repeat with json data

Tags: json, angularjs

I have the following json data saved in json column in postgres database

```
{
  "runway": [
    {"number":"13R/13L", "length":"14511", "lengthuom":"ft"},
    {"number":"10R/15L", "length":"98641", "lengthuom":"ft"}, 
    {"number":"16R/22L", "length":"65410", "lengthuom":"ft"} 
  ]
}
```

I'm tryig to get it by ng-repeat but I don't know how.

I try with the following code

```
<tr ng-repeat="ass in assetb track by $index">
    <td>{{ass.runway.number}}</td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone help me please to display this data in table?

Comment: What does your assetb  contain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this may help you :--

```js
function MyController($scope){
  var data = {"runway":[ {"number":"13R/13L", "length":"14511", "lengthuom":"ft"},
 {"number":"10R/15L", "length":"98641", "lengthuom":"ft"}, 
 {"number":"16R/22L", "length":"65410", "lengthuom":"ft"} ]}
  
  $scope.list = data.runway;
 }
```

```html
<html ng-app>
<head>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <p ng-repeat="l in list track by $index">{{l.number}}</p>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get your data from database and store it in `$scope` variable. Something like:

```
$scope.assetb = {
  "runway": [
    {"number":"13R/13L", "length":"14511", "lengthuom":"ft"},
    {"number":"10R/15L", "length":"98641", "lengthuom":"ft"}, 
    {"number":"16R/22L", "length":"65410", "lengthuom":"ft"} 
  ]
};
```

And since `ng-repeat` requires an array, modify your HTML something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ass in assetb.runway track by $index">
   <td>{{ass.number}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line track by $index and use like

```
<tr ng-repeat="ass in assetb.runway">
     <td>{{ass.number}}</td>
</tr>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/2239/)